# Backbone.js validate collection

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

[Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) offers validation for models. But there is no a simple way to check all models in collection are valid. No `.isValid` property for collections.

I use a hack like this:

```
_.isEmpty(_.filter(myCollection.models, function(m) {return m.validationError;}))
```

Is there more optimized way to 'validate' collection?

Comment: Seems like just iterating through your collection and checking .isValid would do what you're asking. Use .each to do the iteration...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using [some](http://underscorejs.org/#some) method?

```
var hasErrors = _.some(myCollection.models, function(m) {
    return m.validationError;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's obviously more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

The BackboneJS Collection [delegates](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) some UnderscoreJS methods like [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some). You could use it like that:

```
var hasErrors = myCollection.some(function(model) {
    return model.validationError;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[lodash.js](http://lodash.com/) supports construction like this (with "_.pluck" callback shorthand):

```
_.some(myCollection.models, 'validationError');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but please look at my decision to this problem. In short, it is available as github repo [backbone-collection-validation](https://github.com/vogdb/backbone-collection-validation). Now, to details. To validate collection like this

```
Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  validate: function (collection) {
    var nonExistIds = [];
    _.forEach(collection, function (model) {
      var friends = model.get('friends');
      if (friends && friends.length) {
        for (var i = friends.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if (!this.get(friends[i])) {
            nonExistIds.push(friends[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }, this);
    if (nonExistIds.length) {
      return 'Persons with id: ' + nonExistIds + ' don\'t exist in the collection.';
    }
  }
})
```

You need to extend your Backbone with this

```
//This implementation is called simple because it
// * allows to set invalid models into collection. Validation only will trigger
//   an event 'invalid' and nothing more.
var parentSet = Backbone.Collection.prototype.set;

Backbone.Collection.prototype.set = function (models, options) {
  var parentResult = parentSet.apply(this, arguments);
  if (options && options.validate) {
    if (!_.isFunction(this.validate)) {
      throw new Error('Cannot validate a collection without the `validate` method');
    }
    var errors = this.validate(this.models);
    if (errors) {
      this.trigger('invalid', this, errors);
    }
  }
  return parentResult;
};
```

or with this

```
//This implementation is called advanced because it
// * doesn't allow to set invalid models into collection.

var parentSet = Backbone.Collection.prototype.set;

Backbone.Collection.prototype.set = function (models, options) {
  if (!options || !options.validate) {
    return parentSet.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
    if (!_.isFunction(this.validate)) {
      throw new Error('Cannot validate a collection without the `validate` method');
    }

    var clones = [];
    _.forEach(this.models, function (model) {
      clones.push(model.clone());
    }, this);
    var exModels = this.models;
    this.reset(clones);
    var exSilent = options.silent;
    options.silent = true;
    parentSet.apply(this, arguments);

    var errors = this.validate(this.models);

    this.reset(exModels);
    if (typeof exSilent === 'undefined') {
      delete options.silent;
    } else {
      options.silent = exSilent;
    }
    if (errors) {
      this.trigger('invalid', this, errors);
      return this;
    } else {
      return parentSet.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
};
```